# What packages are required to package a DEB file in Netbeans?

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, jar, deb

I am trying to package a Java SE project with Netbeans Native Packaging. While there are plenty of instructions for doing this on Windows, I cannot find the required packages for doing so on Ubuntu with a Debian package.

What do I need to install on my system to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

if you're free to choose a buildsystem there're rpm and deb packaging plugins for [`gradle`](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-gradle-rpm-plugin), [`maven`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/unix/) and even `ant tasks` for [deb](https://code.google.com/p/ant-deb-task/) and [rpm](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/rpm.html).

The resulted packages are somewhat limited, but if you don't something special like precise file permissions control, or rpm install triggers etc, they may help you.

Comment: I'm asking about the built-in native packager tool in Netbeans 7.4 and 8.0.

Comment: Don't know if it could help but nevertheless https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html